# UICollectionView add gap between cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I'm using `ALAssetsLibrary` to access system photo library to preview and multiple select photos,which is like the origin system photo library and I can scroll to preview photos.I implement it by `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.Everything goes well except a little issue.

When I use iOS system photo library and scroll to preview photos,there is a **Gap** between two photos like below.
[image]

While in my app,there is is no **Gap** between the two photos when scrolling.I set `UICollectionView` paged and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` cell space(`minimumLineSpacing` and `minimumInteritemSpacing`) to zero both.
[image]

How can I make my photo preview like system photo library with a **Gap** between two scrolling photos?I am new to `UICollectionView`,and I am not sure if the **Gap** is implemented by `SupplementaryView` or anything else.

Comment: Reduce the width of ImageView in `UICollectionViewCell` by adding `10px` to both sides. I mean if the collection view cell width is `320px`, give image width as `300px` and align vertically center.

Comment: But I want to display photos full screen and have gap only when scrolling,just like the iOS system photo library.Your approach show photos not in full screen.@SriKanth

Comment: have you implemented minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex  and minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex delegate method ?

Comment: You have to maintain two `UICollectionViewFlowLayout ` objects to achieve this. One for full screen width and one for gap, just change the item size for each layout and when user enables preview mode change the layout using `performBatchUpdates` block method of `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in

1. Set the UICollectionView frame width larger than screen width.

   ```
   layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
   CGRect cSize = self.view.bounds;
   layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
   // 1. UICollectionView frame width lager than screen with => Screen width + 2*(required Space)
   cSize.size.width += 20; 
   self.collectionGallery = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:cSize collectionViewLayout:layout];
   layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
   layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
   layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
   ```
2. Set UIImageView frame width equal to screen width.

   ```
   -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   GalleryCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   cell.imageGallery.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
   // 2
   cell.imageGallery.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

   return cell;
   }
   ```
3. Cell width should be larger than screen width, same as in step 1.

   ```
   -(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width + 20, self.view.frame.size.height); // cell size should be same as collectionview width
   return size;
   }
   ```

Hope this will help you.
Please do comment and vote up if this solves your problem

Comment: It's quite a smart way and exactly work! I also succeed by autolayout.Thanks!

Comment: Btw,the number of section or the number of item in section does not matter to the gap.The key is to set the `UICollectionView` frame width larger than screen width and `UIImageView` frame equals to screen width.Would you please improve your answer?

Comment: @Xingxing Thankyou for you support and i have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the property `.itemSize = CGSizeMake(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);` of your flow layout to the size desired for the images pages.

After this, `.minimumInteritemSpacing` will works fine.

To do the change between preview and collection, use two FlowLayout, one with gap and one without gap.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum Spacing and Section Insets will do the work for you.

dont do this -> cell space(minimumLineSpacing and minimumInteritemSpacing) to zero both.

Answer (score 1):

This UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate method will help you..

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section  
  {
    return 10; // This is the minimum inter item spacing, can be more
  }
```

One more if you need more space to arrange your cells adjust the edgeInsets also

Answer (score 1):

Use this below code, if use `miniumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:`,  spacing between 5px in each item and you need margins, set the value of this method top,left,bottom,right in `insetForSectionAtIndex:`,

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *) collectionView 
                        layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *) collectionViewLayout 
        insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger) section {

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0); // top, left, bottom, right
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *) collectionView
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *) collectionViewLayout
  minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger) section {    
    return 5.0;
}
```

hope its helpful